# closing an opening java servers and clients

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a java server running and an android client which connects to it. I can successfully send and receive data from the first android activity.

What I want to do is, when I click my login button (which works), I want to close the connection in the one activity (home page), stop the server, restart the server and open a new connection in the redirected page.

When I close the client's connection (and restart the server) and restart the client in the next page, something must be wrong because my server restarts, but the second android activity starts and connects to the server, but never accepts or receives the I/O streams. I never get confirmation of the I/O streams.

Could it be that I create the socket only once in my server??

**Server:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
         SASSServer s = new SASSServer();
  }
  public SASSServer()
  { 
    try {
        BuildUI();
        setTitle("SASS Server");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SASSServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
  public void BuildUI() throws IOException
 {

    // create keypad
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

            /*
            enterField = new JTextField();
    enterField.setEnabled(true);

    enterField.addActionListener(

    new ActionListener() {
        // send message to client
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            sendData(event.getActionCommand());
        }
    }

    );

            p.add(enterField);*/
       p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 2, 2));

            ConnectServer = new JButton("Connect to server");
            p.add(ConnectServer);

            ConnectDatabase = new JButton("Connect to database");
            p.add(ConnectDatabase);

            CloseServer = new JButton("Close Server");
            p.add(CloseServer);

    add("Center", p);

             addWindowListener(this);
            addWindowFocusListener(this);
            addWindowStateListener(this);
            ConnectServer.addActionListener(this);
            ConnectDatabase.addActionListener(this);
            CloseServer.addActionListener(this);

            Create a ServerSocket.
        server = new ServerSocket(5001, 100);
  }
  public void runServer() throws Exception 
  {
    try 
            {

    while (true) {

            // Step 2: Wait for a connection.
            waitForConnection();

            // Step 3: Get input and output streams.
            getStreams();

            // Step 4: Process connection.
            processConnections();

            // Step 5: Close connection.
            closeConnection();
            ++counter;

        }
    } 
            catch (EOFException eofException) 
            {
        System.out.println("Client terminated connection");
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }

}

  // wait for connectionto arrive, then display connection info
   private void waitForConnection() throws IOException 
  {
    System.out.println("Waiting for connection\n");

    connection = server.accept();

    System.out.println("Connection " + counter + " received from: "
            + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
  }

  // get streams to send and receive data
  private void getStreams() throws IOException 
  {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        output.flush();

        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("\nGot I/O streams\n");
  }


   private void sendData(String message) 
   {
    try 
    {
            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("\nCLIENT>>>" + message);
    } 
    catch (IOException ioException) 
    {
            System.out.println("\nError writing object");
    }
  }

  // close streams and socket
  private void closeConnection() throws IOException 
   {
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("\nUser terminated connection");
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(SASSServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

  // process connection with client
public void processConnections() throws Exception
{
    String message = "SERVER>>> Connection successful";
        output.writeObject(message);
        output.flush();
        do 
        {
                try 
                {
                        message = (String) input.readObject();
                        if (message.equals("TERMINATE"))
                        {
                            closeConnection();
                            runServer();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println("XML string being created into document : " + message);
                        Document d = CreateDocumentFromString(message);
                        String xmlname = "ServerData.xml";
                        x.saveDoc(d, xmlname);
                        processXML(xmlname);            
                        System.out.println("Document " + xmlname + " has been created" );
                        System.out.println("\n Message: " + message);
                        }
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) 
                {
                        System.out.println("\nUnknown object type received");
                }
        } 
        while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>> TERMINATE"));
  }
```

**Client:**

```
    // the thread that will be communicating with the server
    public class ServerConnection extends Thread 
    {
        // the I/O streams that will be receiving/sending data from/to the
        // server
        private ObjectOutputStream output;
        private ObjectInputStream input;

        private Socket client;

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                // Step 1: Create a Socket to make connection
                connectToServer();

                // Step 2: Get the input and output streams
                getStreams();

                // Step 3: Process connection
                processConnection();

                // Step 4: Close connection
                //closeConnection();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.e("CONNECTION", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
            addMessage("Attempting connection\n");
            client = new Socket(##IP Address##, 5001);
            addMessage("Connected to: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }

        private void getStreams() throws IOException 
        {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            connection.sendData("You got the streams");
            addMessage("Got I/O streams");
        }



        private void processXML(String m) throws Exception
        {

               addMessage(m);
        }

        public void processConnection() throws Exception 
        {   

                    do 
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            message = (String) input.readObject();
                            addMessage(message);
                            processXML(message);
                        } 
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) 
                        {
                            addMessage("ERROR: Unknown object type received");
                        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    while (!message.equals("SERVER>>> TERMINATE"));         
        }

        private void sendData(String message) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(message);
                output.flush();
                addMessage("CLIENT>>>" + message);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                addMessage("ERROR: Error writing object");
            }
        }

        private void closeConnection() throws IOException {
            addMessage("Closing connection");
            output.close();
            input.close();
            client.close();
        }

    }
```

**Manifest:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="example02"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="AddTutor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_tutor" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InsertTutor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_insert_tutor" >
    </activity>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

I run the exact same client code in both android activities, but yet the second activity just never gets my streams.
Please tell me where I am going wrong because I am pulling my hair out with frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I was being very silly. I forgot to add the internet permissions in my manifest. For anyone who has this problem, I've solved it.